# Use of unresolved identifier 'present' - the present method doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm going to use `UIAlertController` but when I want to present it I see this error:

> use of unresolved identifier 'present'

This is my code :

```
func showAllert(title: String, msg: String, vc: UIViewController){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You have to call `present` on a view controller. What ever class this `showAllert` method is in isn't a `UIViewController` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to specifically use `vc: UIViewController` to present the alert you should call the method this way:

```
vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that your presenting view controller name is VC instead of present. If you do `vc(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`
It will work.

Comment: @Muhammad Rashid: are you saying `present` is the name of the view controller?

Comment: Maybe you mean vc.present